# My AVL insert is slow. How can I make it faster?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to optimize my AVL tree. Without self-balancing the tree creation of 1 million nodes is super fast. But as soon as I add rotations it gets very slow. I suspect it's caused by calculating the height or balance, but I'm unable to find the right fix.

What should I do to make the rebalancing efficient?

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *left, *right, *parent;
}NODE;

int insert(int val,NODE **root,NODE *par){
    NODE *temp;
    NODE *new;

    if(*root == NULL){
        new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        new->value = val;
        new->left = NULL;
        new->right = NULL;
        new->parent = par;
        *root = new;
        rotate(*root);
        return 1;
    }

    temp = *root;
    if(val == temp->value){
        //printf("Node already exist\n"); //X
        return 0;
    }
    if(val < temp->value){
        insert(val,&temp->left,temp);
    }
    if(val > temp->value){
        insert(val,&temp->right,temp);
    }
}

void rotate(NODE* root){
    NODE* p;
    p = root;
    while(p != NULL){
        rotation(p);
        p = p->parent;
    }
}

void rotation(NODE *root){
    NODE* temp;
    int balance = get_balace(root);
    if(balance > 1){
        if(get_balace(root->left) >= 1){
            right_rotate(root);
        }else if(get_balace(root->left) <= -1){
            left_rotate(root->left);
            right_rotate(root);
        }
    }else if(balance < -1){
        if(get_balace(root->right) <= -1){
            left_rotate(root);
        }else if(get_balace(root->right) >= 1){
            right_rotate(root->right);
            left_rotate(root);
        }
    }
}

int get_height(NODE *root){
    int left_h, right_h;
    if(root == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    left_h = get_height(root->left);
    right_h = get_height(root->right);
    return 1 + max(left_h,right_h);
}

int get_balace(NODE *root){
    return get_height(root->left) - get_height(root->right);
}
```

The rotation functions are just basic rotations with only logic.

I tried changing the `balance` and `height` functions. I managed to make `height` slightly faster by calculating `left_h` and `right_h` separately instead like `return 1 + max(get_height(root->left),get_height(root->right));`

What else can be done to make it faster?

Comment: Why does `int insert()` sometimes not return anything?  Tip: Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: With [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Balance_factor) trees, I expect the balance factor is saved in the node rather than expensive  `get_balace(NODE *root)`.  Only need 2 bits.  So of course this code is slow.

Comment: Sorry I meant returning something in insert(). I dont really see why it's necessary. Also i posted node.

Comment: Avoid confusing code so we can focus on the key issue.  Either have `int insert()` return a value in all paths, or use `void insert()` and don't return anything.

Comment: Also how would i implement balance factor in node? Wouldn't updating it be as costly as this approach?

Comment: The balance factor (BF) looks at the 2 children's BF only to know its rotation needs and its BF.  Less costly than a depth search.  BF is a key innovations of AVL.

Comment: "Wouldn't updating it be as costly as this approach" No it will not if done correctly. The method is described everywhere, but the gist of it is as follows. The height of the tree increases if the height of the *higher of the two subtrees* increases, which *can only* (but does not always) happen if you insert in that subtree.

Comment: Oh so my problem is calling `get_balance()` too much in the `rotation()`? But i dont really know how would i update the BF

Comment: @meTju, "But i dont really know how would i update the BF" --> so do you want someone to write code for you or do you want to research your AVL notes more?  The wiki has sample code.

Comment: A good implementation of BF doesn't ever need to call a function like `get_height`. All can be done with just inspecting current BF values and no recursion. It's all explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not efficient to calculate heights of subtrees (after a node is inserted) in an AVL tree. What's more, it is not needed to know the height of a subtree to implement a correctly functioning AVL tree. It is enough to store with each node the balance factor (bf). Each type of rotation can derive what the change in balance factors has to be to keep that information consistent.

The Wikipedia article on [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) has quite some detail on the algorithms to use for rotating and keeping these balance factors up to date. Note that the rotation functions have preconditions and are only expected to give reliable results when they are called when **needed** to rebalance a tree.

Here is an implementation:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value, bf;
    struct node *left, *right;
} Node;

Node* createNode(int val) {
    Node* newNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->value = val;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->bf = 0;
    return newNode;
}

void rotateLeft(Node **x) {
    Node *z = (*x)->right;
    (*x)->right = z->left;
    z->left = *x;
    (*x)->bf = +!z->bf;
    z->bf = -(*x)->bf;
    *x = z;
}

void rotateRight(Node **x) {
    Node *z = (*x)->left;
    (*x)->left = z->right;
    z->right = *x;
    (*x)->bf = -!z->bf;
    z->bf = -(*x)->bf;
    *x = z;
}

void rotateRightLeft(Node **x) {
    Node *z = (*x)->right;
    Node *y = z->left;
    z->left = y->right;
    y->right = z;
    (*x)->right = y->left;
    y->left = *x;
    (*x)->bf = -(y->bf > 0);
    z->bf = +(y->bf < 0);
    y->bf = 0;
    *x = y;
}

void rotateLeftRight(Node **x) {
    Node *z = (*x)->left;
    Node *y = z->right;
    z->right = y->left;
    y->left = z;
    (*x)->left = y->right;
    y->right = *x;
    (*x)->bf = +(y->bf < 0);
    z->bf = -(y->bf > 0);
    y->bf = 0;
    *x = y;
}

#define ABSENT_BF 9
void insert(Node **node, int value) {
    if (!*node) {
        *node = createNode(value);
        return;
    }
    int side = value < (*node)->value ? -1 : 1;
    Node **child = side == -1 ? &((*node)->left) : &((*node)->right); 
    int origBF = *child ? (*child)->bf : ABSENT_BF;
    insert(child, value);
    if (origBF == ABSENT_BF || origBF == 0 && (*child)->bf != 0) { // Height changed
        if ((*node)->bf != side) { // The bf update will stay in range
            (*node)->bf += side; // Do it.
        // In all other cases a rotation is needed:
        } else if (side == -1) {
            if ((*child)->bf > 0) {
                rotateLeftRight(node); 
            } else {
                rotateRight(node);
            }
        } else {
            if ((*child)->bf < 0) {
                rotateRightLeft(node);
            } else {
                rotateLeft(node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```