# Is this correct way to identify which rotation should i use in balancing a BST?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I programmed this function to identify which rotation to use.idk if its correct because iam a beginner.Is there a better way to do it or my function is just fine?

```
int Binary_Tree::check_which_pattern_has_occured(Node_BT* p_root) {
    bool step_sequence[2]{false,false};
    Node_BT *temp1= p_root;  
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (temp1 == nullptr) {
            return linking_pattern::no_pattern;
        }
        else if (get_height_of_BT_structure(temp1->mp_left) < get_height_of_BT_structure(temp1->mp_right)) {
            temp1 = temp1->mp_right;          
            step_sequence[i]=1;
        }
        else if (get_height_of_BT_structure(temp1->mp_left) > get_height_of_BT_structure(temp1->mp_right)) {
            temp1 = temp1->mp_left;        
            step_sequence[i] = 0;
        }
        else {
            return linking_pattern::no_pattern;
        }
    }
   
    if ((step_sequence[0]==0)&&(step_sequence[1]==0)) {
        return linking_pattern::zigzig_left;
    }
    else if ((step_sequence[0] == 1) && (step_sequence[1] == 1)) {
        return linking_pattern::zigzig_right;
    }
    else if ((step_sequence[0] == 1) && (step_sequence[1] == 0)) {
        return linking_pattern::zigzag_right_left;
    }
    else if ((step_sequence[0] == 0) && (step_sequence[1] == 1)) {
        return linking_pattern::zigzag_left_right;
    }
    else return linking_pattern::no_pattern;
   
}
```

when i use this function and do the rotations it works but not completly the height decreases a lot and all the nodes are there but when i run a is_BT_balanced function at some node it shows me it isnt balanced.should it be balanced at every node and does anybody might have an idea what could be wrong

i tried doing rotations with diffrent kinds of BT traversal.I tried using others people function for checking if the tree is balanced.i went thru code multiple times and now iam just lost.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see whether it matches your exceptations?

Comment: @Quimby i did and the function gives back the correct pattern but the tree still isn't balanced at all nodes.is there a particular way to do balancing that i'm missing

Comment: It is not efficient to calculate the height of the two subtrees. Instead you should keep a trace of the *balance factor*. See [Wikipedia's article on AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree). It has all the info you need to decide on and perform rotations.

Comment: Have a look at [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75734649/5459839) in C.

Comment: @trincot       Thank you for your help. Your suggestion is much better than my implementation of rotations.I have only one question what does +! means in this block of code (*x)->bf = +!z->bf;

Comment: The `!` is the "not" operator and will give 1 when the operand is 0, and 0 otherwise. The `+` doesn't do anything, but I wanted to mirror the `-` that is used in the opposite rotation function.